# iphone I can have access to methods but they can't access the properties

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar

I have UIViewController a tabbar with many UINavigationController. The tabbar is created programatically. when I click the first UITabItem it shows a UITable and when I click it again it shows the maps so I can switch between them. The UITable and the MKMapView are in same view and I switch between them using sethidden yes or no. The problem is that this does not work, I found out why but I don't why it's happening
here is the code of the functions that do the hiding and the showing:

```
    -(void) showMap
    {
        fieldsTableView.hidden = YES;
        [mapView setHidden:NO];
    }
    -(void) showList
    {
        fieldsTableView.hidden = NO;
        mapView.hidden = YES;
    }
```

and here is the code that calls these methods:

```
    -(void) showFieldsView
    {
        @try 
        {
            if(self.fieldsViewController == nil) 
            {
                self.fieldsViewController = [[FieldsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FieldsView" bundle:nil];
            }
            if(currentViewController == nil)
            {
                [self showFieldsListView];
                currentViewController = fieldsNavController;

            }

            NSString *viewtype = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[(UITabBarItem *)[self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] title]];
            if(currentViewController == self.fieldsNavController)
            {
                if (viewtype == @"List")
                {

                    [(UITabBarItem *)[self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:@"Map"];
                    [(UITabBarItem *)[self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map.png"]];
                    [fieldsViewController showMap];
                }
                else
                {

                    [self.fieldsViewController showList];
                    [(UITabBarItem *)[self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:@"List"];
                    [(UITabBarItem *)[self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"list.png"]];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                [self showFieldsListView];
                currentViewController = self.fieldsNavController;

            }
            [viewtype release];
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"Exception in tabViewControlelr showFieldsView \nDescription %@", [exception description]);
        }

    }
    - (void) showFieldsListView {
        [self.fieldsNavController viewWillAppear:YES];
    [self.fieldsNavController.view addSubview:tabBar];
        [self.view addSubview:self.fieldsNavController.view];
    }
```

I did a NSLOG and this what I found out: when calling the showMap or the showList function, it is called and what inside is done, but the properties are not accessed, it displays NULL (I tried to display another string property and it shows NULL)
here are the declaration:

```
    UITableView * fieldsTableView;
    MKMapView *mapView;
```

and

```
    @property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView * fieldsTableView;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) MKMapView *mapView;
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to name the ivar and the property to the same.

Comment: make breakpoint and chk where are you getting problem...

Comment: Dave: Yes I know, but I didn't start the program from the crash, my task was to add some funcionnalities to an already made program, I'm reading the humain guideline and I'll respect it before submitting to apple
Rajneesh071: I did it, and I aslo did a nslog, it does not show a problem

Comment: Rajneesh071, I found that the fieldViewController has the adress 0x08638a43 but all of its properties have the adress 0x00000000, I don't know why? it is already initialized and so all its properties. I initiate the properties in loadView

Comment: Try to rename your ivars. For example "_mapView".

Comment: is your fieldViewController's nib name is FieldsView

Comment: Dave, do you mean I shall do: @@synthesize mapView=_mapView?
Rajneesh071: yes it is FieldsView.xib, the map and table are loading, I see them but in the breakpoint, they had the adress 0x0000000

Comment: Yes, if you define a property named mapView and an ivar named _mapView, you should synthesize as @synthesize mapView=_mapView; (Do not forget to release it in the dealloc if you are not using ARC.)

Comment: I did it, now it does not want to add objects to arrays, got bad access exception everywhere and it stops the app even if it is inside a try catch block